# Ошибка: get() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, get, parse

Эксперементировал, пробовал "засунуть" рекурсивные функции в `get`. Не вышло. Ошибка:

```
TypeError: get() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Вот код, получает `html` страницы:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HOST ='https://www.goodreads.com'
def get_data(*url):
    headers = {
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        "user-agent": "....36"
    }

    req = requests.get(*url, *headers )
    with open(f"C:\\...\\Roger Zelazny.html", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(req.text)

def main():
    get_data('https://www.goodreads.com/search?page=1&q=+Roger+Zelazny&qid=ems5pajO3W&tab=books','https://www.goodreads.com/search?page=2&q=+Roger+Zelazny&qid=ems5pajO3W&tab=books')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Можно ли обойти эту ошибку и все же, "засунуть несколько значений в `get`" (>2)?

Или это невозможно?

UPD Изменил код, но по прежнему обрабатывает только первый url:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HOST ='https://www.goodreads.com'
def get_data(*url):
    headers = {
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        "user-agent": "..../537.36"
    }

    for i in range(0, 1):
        req = requests.get(url[i], headers=headers)

        with open(f"C:\\....\\Parsing\\Roger Zelazny{i}.html", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(req.text)

def main():
     get_data('https://www.goodreads.com/search?page=1&q=+Roger+Zelazny&qid=ems5pajO3W&tab=books','https://www.goodreads.com/search?page=2&q=+Roger+Zelazny&qid=ems5pajO3W&tab=books')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `req = requests.get(*url, *headers )`  на  `req = requests.get(url[0], headers=headers)`

Comment: [def get(url, params=None, **kwargs)](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py) не выйдет с *, там один позиционный аргумент ps в чем была идея? избавиться от цикла запросов?

Comment: В вызове функции - два url . Get запрос должен обработать два, по идее. Обрабатывает один. Хотя вот ручками - тогда да:url[0] или url[1] - соотвественно  -первая и вторая страницы. Меняем ручками. Ну и with open(f"C:\\...\\Roger Zelazny2.html - номера страниц меняем, соотвественно.- тогда работает.

Comment: параметр stop в range: Generate numbers up to, but not including this number, т.е. for i in range(0, 1) == [0]

Comment: Да, все срослось. Благодарю. Практически - пагинация получается.

Comment: а зачем пишете html в файл? такое задание? не проще ли достать нужные данные и записать только их?

Comment: Так лучше парсеры кодить. Безопаснее, по крайне мер. Сначала сохранять html страницу, потом обрабатывать, чтобы сайт не "долбить" запросами. Вот код без пагинации: https://github.com/Joffrey-ops/Joffrey/blob/main/Roger%2BZelazny Вот результат: https://github.com/Joffrey-ops/Joffrey/blob/main/Roger%20Zelazny02.xlsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой код должен помочь:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HOST ='https://www.goodreads.com'
def get_data(*urls): # url -> urls
    headers = {
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        "user-agent": "..../537.36"
    }

    for i, url in enumerate(urls): # бежим по переданным  url'ам
        req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

        with open(f"C:\\....\\Parsing\\Roger Zelazny{i}.html", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(req.text)

def main():
     get_data('https://www.goodreads.com/search?page=1&q=+Roger+Zelazny&qid=ems5pajO3W&tab=books','https://www.goodreads.com/search?page=2&q=+Roger+Zelazny&qid=ems5pajO3W&tab=books')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```